# SSL error for HSTS enabled site with Self Signed certificate

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, microsoft-edge, self-signed

I created a self signed wild card certificate (*.website.local) on our internal environment which can be accessed using an internal DNS URL (ex: https://site1.website.local).
I have HSTS enabled for the purpose of testing I want to enforce it.
When browsing to the site using Edge I would see the following error.

Error:

> Your connection is not private.
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from website.local (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID. website.local normally uses encryption to protect your information. When Chrome tried to connect to website.local this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. This may happen when an attacker is trying to pretend to be website.local, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has interrupted the connection. Your information is still secure because Chrome stopped the connection before any data was exchanged.
>
> You cannot visit website.local right now because the website sent scrambled credentials that Chrome cannot process. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later.

I know the work around is to type in **thisisunsafe** or **badidea** and it would work after that.

It would be nice to not having to type this in and instead do something to make the browser recognized that I trust my own self sign certificate. I attempted to put the certificate into my Trusted Root CA but it does not help.  Do you know of any other steps I can try?

Comment: *"I attempted to put the certificate into my Trusted Root CA but it does not help."* - then you likely did this wrong or the certificate is not a CA certificate. Please provide more details about the certificate (ideally the PEM), if the certificate can actually be seen as trusted in the root CA store of the client (it does not help to be in the servers trust CA store) and how you access the site (URL must match certificate).  *"any other steps"* - adding the certificate is trusted is the way to go, but make sure it is done right.

Comment: Which version of OS are you using? I see the error message shows "Chrome" and in your description you say "Edge", I think the issue happens in both browsers. Does the issue also happen in other browsers like Firefox?

Comment: Having the same issue for cockpit